Servo "Magic" With External Power Supply
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 180;
  // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(8);  // attaches the servo on pin 8 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }

Basically the idea should be pretty clear here. I’m trying to move this servo using my Arduino Uno and an external DC power source.
When I upload the above code the servo will move a little as shown but then it will get very strange, almost magical. It starts “twitching” around almost and won’t really respond. The servo is rated for 6-7.4 volts so that should be fine.
Now I would think this must be a noise issue with the signal from the Arduino however when I hook the servo up to the 5 V power source built into the system, it works perfectly. Thus it must be an issue with the external power source.
Any help on what’s happening here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Note: Adding a capacitor over the power rails to the servo doesn’t help so I don’t think it’s noise from the dc power supply

Make sure your servo pin is a PWM pin. On Arduino uno: 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 11.

You can see from the pin description that it has the symbol "~" on it.
